# Add a condition to accept just caracters and digits to a javascript

Tags: javascript, formatting

I have a javascript code which format in input field to the following format : 
 xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

I want also beside the formatting to add condition to accept juste caracters and digits /^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/ how can do that inside the function?

this is my input:

```
  <div>{{ form_widget(form.lien, {'attr':{'class': 'form-control' ,'placeholder' :' Format xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx' ,'maxlength' : '19','onkeypress':'keyPressLien(event,"'~form.lien.vars.id~'");'   }}) }}</div>
```

**this is the javascript function:**

```
   function keyPressLien(e, id) {
            var phone = document.getElementById(id);

            var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]$/;

            if (e.key !== "Backspace") {
                if (phone.value.length === 4) {
                    phone.value = phone.value + '-';
                }
                if (phone.value.length === 9) {
                    phone.value = phone.value + '-';
                }
                if (phone.value.length === 14) {
                    phone.value = phone.value + '-';
                }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to mention, you do not have to use a JS. You can set the regex directly to `input` by `pattern` attribute. Example:

```
<input type="text" name="phone" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]" title="Phone number">
```

Note that, the `pattern` is accepted only when `type="text"`, not `number` or anything other.
For more information about the usage of `pattern`, check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you described xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx can be found exactly with the regular expression:

```
(\w{4}-){3}(\w{4})
```

if you wanted to extend this to any number of 'xxxx-' patterns, then a final terminating 'xxxx', you can change the '{3}' after the first grouping into a '+'

```
(\w{4}-)+(\w{4})
```

but this would also find match with groupings that just happen to have four alphanumeric characters on either side of a hyphen, so if you know you want exactly 16 alphanumeric character with hyphens every 4 characters, use the first one.

You can use Notepad++'s CTRL+F feature along with a regex cheat sheet to develop more advanced regex strings for matching input in such an exact way. Make sure you leave enough comments to remind yourself or another developer about what your regex string is supposed to be doing!!